# PHP Cannot connect to PDO ODBC Driver

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, pdo, odbc

My php cannot find my odbc driver. I've downloaded and re-installed multiple times. Can anyone help me with this error:

```
QLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data
source name not found and no default driver specified"
```

Here is my php code:

```
$dbName = "C:\Users\David\Documents\SCHOOLNEW\Assignment5-PROG1800\database\as4.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName))
{
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
try 
{
    // Connect
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\Users\David\Documents\SCHOOLNEW\Assignment5-PROG1800\database\as4.mdb;Uid=Admin");

    // INSERT data
    $count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO part(vendorNo,description,onHand,onOrder,cost,listPrice) VALUES ('$vendorNo', '$desc', '$onHand', '$onOrder', '$cost', '$listPrice')");

    // echo the number of affected rows
    echo $count;

    // close the database connection
    $dbh = null;

}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I'm running `php with apache on xampp`. This all on a local machine. My system is 64 bits. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the system and drive types or my syntax or certain drivers I need to install. I just want to insert data from my form into the database on my computer.

Comment: Have your PHP script `echo (8 * PHP_INT_SIZE) . "-bit<br/>";`. What does it display?

Comment: It displays 32 bit. Im thinking this is an issue with the 32bit and 64 bit version of OBCD getting confused.

Comment: Yes, it is almost certainly a "bitness" issue. However, since your PHP code is running in the 32-bit environment and you're opening an .mdb file you can use `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}` (without the `, *.accdb`) and it should work. (Note also that there is a space: `Driver (`.)

Comment: oh my gosh....that space fixed it! Thank you Gord THANK YOU. I was up so late trying to fix this! It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb)}
```

is not a valid ODBC driver name because it is missing a space. The correct name for the newer "ACE" ODBC driver is

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}
```

However, in this case PHP is running in the 32-bit environment and trying to open an .mdb database so the older "Jet" ODBC driver ...

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}
```

... will work, too.

Comment: ... and available names can be found at ODBC administrator in control panel, though it's rather tricky to ensure you open the one that belongs to the correct architecture (32 or 64 bit).

Answer (score 0):

Can you place the path after escaping the slashes and then try:-

```
$dbName = "C:\\Users\\David\\Documents\\SCHOOLNEW\\Assignment5-PROG1800\\database\\as4.mdb";
```

Escape the slashes in all the paths you have provided in the code and then try.