# ODBC data source of windows does not work

Tags: ms-access, pdo, driver, datasource

I allow myself to post my problem, having been looking for the solution for more than two hours, without finding the least solution.

Context: I want to connect to an Access database thanks to the PHP PDO. For that, I have the following code:

```
public function connect () {
    $this->dsn = 'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};charset=UTF-8;Dbq='.$this->dbway.';Uid=;Pwd=;';
    $this->user = '';
    $this->password = '';
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->password);
        die("'eee");
    }catch (\PDOException $e) {
        die('Error  : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

$this->dbway = absolute path to the .mdb database

When i try this, i've this response : 
    Error : : SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][Gestionnaire de pilotes ODBC] Source de donnΘes introuvable et nom de pilote non spΘcifiΘ

Obviously, I tried to find the solution by searching the internet before.

I checked in the administration of ODBC data sources, in the "system data sources", I have:
Name: Microsoft Access Driver
Platform: 32 bits
Driver: Microsoft Access Driver (* .mdb)

So I tried to add the same thing in the user odbc data sources, without success.

I also tried to add the Microsoft Access Driver (* .mdb, * .accdb), which always returns the same error.

Moreover, I checked in php.ini and phpForApache.ini that extension = php_odbc.dll and extension = php_pdo_odbc.dll are really active in PHP extensions, and that's the case

I admit I do not know where to look, and where my concern might come from.

Knowing that the database is present, and that in the ODBC data sources, I see the driver in question, I do not understand why I still can not conquer me.

Thanks to those who will take the time to read me,

have a good day :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem description. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And take the tour!

Comment: Also by posting a non-English error message you are severely limiting the amount of people who can help you.

Comment: Google translate from French:  `[ODBC Driver Manager] Data source not found and unspecified driver name`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Cannot connect to PDO ODBC Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417549/php-cannot-connect-to-pdo-odbc-driver)

Comment: Are you using a x64 bit version of PHP? (likely, and your web server also likely x64). This means that you have to install the x64 bit version of the "ace" database engine. (or if you actually using Access UI/system also, then you need to install access x64 bits. Or you can ensure that both your web server and PHP version is x32.